# Nginx memory leak?

Tags: nginx

Upon noticing nginx having failed, a status report confirms the inactive status:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Wed 2022-09-14 03:48:56 UTC; 1h 49min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 300175 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 300189 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 300203 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 76.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
```

After a `sudo service nginx restart`:

```
 service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-09-14 05:39:37 UTC; 3min 22s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 349112 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 349113 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 349125 (nginx)
      Tasks: 25 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 225.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─349114 Passenger watchdog
             ├─349117 Passenger core
             ├─349125 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─349130 nginx: worker process
             ├─349791 Passenger AppPreloader: /.../simon/current
             └─349870 Passenger RubyApp: /.../simon/current (development)
```

At present I only see a huge available memory drop for a server that was not all that active.

a) is the analysis of a memory issue (leak?) correct?
b) how can this be mitigated?

**Update**
within less than an hour (54 minutes):

```
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-09-14 05:39:37 UTC; 54min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 349112 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 349113 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 349125 (nginx)
      Tasks: 30 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 376.3M
```

for 35 lines of access.log and 8 lines of error.log
**Update 2**
The following data were observed over 30+ hours until nginx fell over anew:

```
1h 36min ago
     Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 548.7M

4h 49min ago
      Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 566.2M

 8h ago
      Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 569.0M

10h ago
      Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 568.4M

13h ago
      Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 573.7M
     
14h ago
      Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 580.5M

15h ago
      Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 578.3M
             ├─350286 Passenger RubyApp: /.../simon/current (development)
             ├─350936 Passenger RubyApp: /.../market/current (development)
             └─353112 Passenger RubyApp: /.../fido/current (development)

24h ago
     Tasks: 27 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 297.2M
             ├─389632 nginx: worker process
             └─405094 Passenger RubyApp: /.../fido/current (development)

24h ago
     Tasks: 36 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 513.1M

24h ago
      Tasks: 54 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 673.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─349125 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─389611 Passenger watchdog
             ├─389614 Passenger core
             ├─389632 nginx: worker process
             ├─405094 Passenger RubyApp: /.../fido/current (development)
             ├─408557 Passenger AppPreloader: /.../simon/current
             ├─408640 Passenger RubyApp: /.../simon/current (development)
             ├─408944 Passenger AppPreloader: /.../market/current
             └─409036 Passenger RubyApp: /.../market/current (development)

24h ago
     Tasks: 41 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 591.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─405094 Passenger RubyApp: /.../fido/current (development)
             ├─408640 Passenger RubyApp: /.../simon/current (development)
             └─409036 Passenger RubyApp: /.../market/current (development)

     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Thu 2022-09-15 11:57:46 UTC; 1h 20min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 349112 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 349113 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 349125 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 147.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
```

Observations:
• processes stabilise at 41
• memory stabilised, but after a drop rose somewhat for no real reason.
• nginx seems to put some processes to sleep if unused (drop of threads).
• awakening those applications brings back those processes
The error.log at that time states:

```
2022/09/15 11:57:32 [info] 422864#422864: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2022/09/15 11:57:34 [notice] 422870#422870: signal process started
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:34.2124 422874/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:34.2901 422878/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:34.2903 422878/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:34.3105 422878/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 422878
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:36.4497 422878/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
2022/09/15 11:57:46 [notice] 422902#422902: signal process started

[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:46.0873 422878/T9 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:670 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:46.0874 422878/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1245 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:46.0875 422878/Tb Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:46.0875 422878/Tb Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:46.0875 422878/T9 Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:46.0876 422878/T9 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-09-15 11:57:46.2320 422878/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
```

Comment: Get sample of `service nginx status` command 2-3 days, and update your question. status command which is shared is not comparable as one is taken when service is stopped and another one was after service start I guess.

Comment: just did so.  Withtin 1 hour, the data does seem to reflect a reasonable state.

Comment: What I can say with above details is, your ngnix is not settled yet as number of tasks also increased. Please keep eye on it for at least a day and observe number of tasks and memory consumption.

Comment: did some tracking over 30 or so hours until nginx failed anew.

Comment: I would just create a */15 crontab with `sudo service nginx status | grep -i memory >>/srv/nginx.status_watch` to get a automatic update - remins that it could also php-fpm that eats the memory

Comment: `php-fpm` is an interesting thought; not the first time I see it mentioned. However, no appplication requires it (before dependencies).   `php -v  Command 'php' not found` implies it is not installed.

Comment: Do the creators of NGINX and NGINX-RTMP do any memory profiling before making their code public?